# CSS make a div small with horizontal scrollbar compacts the content

Tags: css

I have a table that I want to make in small div with horizontal (on horizontal)scroll bar (for small device)
I tried to add :

```
overflow-x: auto;
max-height: 100vh;
max-width: 200px;
```

I see the scrollbar but the div content is compacted (see picture), plus I see vertical too which I don't want to have
Am I missing something ??
Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/zzahcq8a/

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you considered using bootstrap, would suit here.

Comment: I am using Typo3, using bootstrap will be complicated and maybe just fixing that div would be easier than Integrating full library for a div, should be some proprety missing

Comment: Have you tried,  clear: both; for one of the divs, elements, If you provide some more code we might be able t help

Comment: @JasonDelaney it didn't work

Comment: Ok well I'd need to see more code like the html all you have given is 3 lines of css, hard to determine...

Comment: @JasonDelaney ok I added it, please check it